# Network Manager works but wlan is unavailable for nmcli

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, networkmanager, wlan

I could connect to my router using the network manager gui on my raspberry pi without any problems. But when I try to do this using nmcli the wifi connection is unavailable (before I connected using the gui and after that). also when I start `nmtui` there isn't a wifi connecction. when I run `nmcli dev status` the output is:

```
wlan0  wifi      unavailable  --
```

What is wrong here? I think its easier to do this using the command line.

Comment: What distribution are you using? Raspbian?

Comment: yes raspbian stretch

Comment: If you edited /etc/network/interfaces manually, NetworkManager stops to manage the interface

Answer (score 4):

In Raspbian, the wireless connections are normally managed by `wpa_supplicant` (also the GUI). Simply installing `network-manager` to use it is not enough as layed out in this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73816/77005), which gives you directions how to make `network-manager` run on Raspbian.

If you don't insist on using `network-manager`, give the command line tool `wpa_cli` of `wpa_supplicant` a try.

Here is how you connect to a network with `wpa_cli` in interactive mode (replace `wlan0` with the name of your wireless interface, `AP_NAME` with the name of your AP, `passphrase` with the passphrase of the AP and `0` with the number that is printed to `stdout` after `ADD_NETWORK`):

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0

> ADD_NETWORK
> SET_NETWORK 0 ssid "AP_NAME"
> SET_NETWORK 0 psk "passphrase"
> ENABLE_NETWORK 0
> quit
```

If you don't want to use interactive mode, you simply need to state the command following the options. See a few examples, here:

If you want to disconnect, use

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 DISCONNECT
```

To list all networks, use

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 LIST_NETWORKS
```

To remove stored network with id=0, use

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 REMOVE_NETWORK 0
```

A list of commands that can be used with `wpa_cli` can be found e.g. [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_cli).

Comment: works. but when i connect to wlan using the pa_cli interactive mode i can't change anything using the "normal" wpa_cli command line options, right? how can i delete connection or disable it in a simple way?

Comment: you can change pretty much everything even outside interactive mode. If you want to disconnect you could use `sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 DISCONNECT`. If you read up on the documentation, you can find the different options. I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You can see your WiFi device status with

```
nmcli radio
```

If the status is "disabled", you can re-enable it; use

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

Thanks to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), [Leopold Vilnius](https://askubuntu.com/users/460187/leopold-vilnius) and [Adriano](https://askubuntu.com/users/513536/adriano) for their answers to
[How to disable wireless from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597116/how-to-disable-wireless-from-command-line) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Just ran into this on raspberry pi (11 (bullseye));  turns out it was due to the supplicant service not running;  it was improperly installed; did an apt-get reinstall wpasupplicant and then did a  sudo systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service and  sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service
 and then rebooted - the gui show shows the local networks to connect  to (and it works) and the nmcli shows the usb networks adapter as connnected;  real puzzler and I hope it helps out someone else